# will the luis end url recognize the entity followed by & symbol

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I used to add an utterance in the following format "difference between zoo, park & garden". But the Luis didn't recognize the entity after **&** symbol.

Is there any restriction to use Symbols before entity.

Comment: where are you putting in the utterance? Is in the the endpoint URL? Or just in the Test blade inside the LUIS portal's UI?

Comment: In endpoint URL

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. If you're sending queries through http GET, the url needs to be **URL-encoded**.

You could try using https://www.bing.com/search?q=url+encode to help encode your url.

So sending in "**difference+between+zoo%2C+park+%26+garden**" as my utterance in the query yielded expected results:

```
{
  "query": "**difference between zoo, park & garden**",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "...",
    "score": ...
  },
  "entities": []
}
```